# Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

Recently I downloaded CelebA dataset from [this page](https://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html). I want to apply some transformations to this data set:

To do it firstly let's define transformations:

```
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets CelebA
celeba_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.CenterCrop(130),
    transforms.Resize([64, 64]),
    transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
```

And now execute it:

```
CelebA(root='img_align_celeba',
       split='train',
       download=False,
       transform=celeba_transforms)
```

However result of this code is an error:

```
Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it
```

Setting `download=True` is also not working. Could you please help me with applying those transformations to this data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue. I'm posting my solution:

**Problem number one**

There is a problem with downloading zip file `img_align_celeba.zip` due to reaching daily quota. Solution to this problem is simply downloading this file from internet e.g. Kaggle.

**Problem number two**

When using function `CelebA` function with `download=True` program will think for a while and then return error mentioned in a question title. Cause of the problem are broken .txt files which I listed below (those files are also downloaded via `CelebA` function):

[image]

For correct working of this function you have to download those .txt files directly from internet. I found them [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7EVK8r0v71pWEZsZE9oNnFzTm8?resourcekey=0-5BR16BdXnb8hVj6CNHKzLg). When you download all of those and replace old ones function `CelebA` should work without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for some copyright/privacy/legal consideration CelebA dataset is slowly going "off-grid".
If you really have to use it, try downloading it from the baidu drive.

Other users report that there might be [download quota issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620356/1714410), and retrying might resolve the issue.

What exactly is the error you get when you try `download=True`?

Comment: I'm exactly obtaining error `"BadZipfile: File is not a zip file"` when `download=True`, (this is exactly the error created by reaching maximum daily quota) thats the reason I abandoned that approach and I download CelebA from page mentioned in the question.

Comment: My question is then: how can I transform this data in case of manual download? Could you please explain to me how your answer corresponds to this question? I don't fully get it...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, i cant comment Johns answer, due to lack of reputation. I just wanted to add, that you also need to unzip the image folder and the image-containing folder should be: `data/celeba/img_align_celeba/000001.jpg`
and so on (`data` is a free to choose folder-name and the parameter you pass to `root = "./data"` in torchs dataset function). In my case, all images had to be moved up one directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).