# Torchvision doesn't see existing folder

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torchvision

I have a question about loading a CelebA dataset into python. Firstly I want to show you what my folder contains:

[image]

after that I run script:

```
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import CelebA

celeba_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.CenterCrop(140),
    transforms.Resize([64, 64]),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

CelebA(root,
       split="train",
       download=True,
       transform=celeba_transforms)
```

And now in the same folder that I showed you, a new file named `img_align_celeba` is created with all the images. However, after everything I obtain error:

```
  File "path\Temp/ipykernel_43204/4255224823.py", line 3, in <module>
    download=False,   transform=celeba_transforms)

  File "path\celeba.py", line 69, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Dataset not found or corrupted.' +

RuntimeError: Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it
```

But I don't understand this error because of two things - I already set `download=True` and second thing is that it should see this folder since it downloaded images to newly created folder. I think the problem maybe somewhere in `torchvision` function `celeba.py` since that function returned the error, but I don't know where is it. Most likely my dataset was downloaded, but function `celeba.py` is looking for it somewhere else. Could you please help me with resolving the issue? I tried to find a solution but I have completely no idea where the problem is

**EDIT**

Solution is here [Dataset not found or corrupted. You can use download=True to download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755609/dataset-not-found-or-corrupted-you-can-use-download-true-to-download-it)

Comment: Did you set `root` to be the path to the downloaded files? According to "celeba.py" you should put the files into a folder called "celeba" and then put that folder under the path that `root` points to. Btw, you can find "celeba.py" where all your python packages are installed.

Comment: I just specified `dataroot` in `CelebA` function.

Comment: This folder exactly which I showed you is named `celeba` and root is pointing exactly that folder. I know that I can find `celeby.py` script but I don't quite know where is the mistake after analyzing it.